# Why parent Controller action gets called instead of child

Tags: symfony, inheritance, controller, routes

I've just stumbled upon this:
Given a particular route, symfony calls the parent controller classes action method instead of the childes.

The `routing.yml` is as simple as it can be:

```
new_message_favorites:
  #there are no routes defined like this with optional parameters
  pattern:   /messages/new/fans
  defaults:  { _controller: BigBundle:VisitorMessages:sendToFavorites }
```

The class that supposed to handle the request is called `VisitorMessagesController` and the action method is called `sendToFavoritesAction` as you might expect:

```
class MessagesController {
  //this one gets called
  public function sendToFavoritesAction(Request $request) { [...] }
}

class VisitorMessagesController extends MessagesController {
  //instead of this
  public function sendToFavoritesAction(Request $request) { [...] }
}
```

Neither of them are defined as services, both are in the right namespace and folders, but instead of the `VisitorMessagesController`s version the parents action gets called when the url is opened.

Note: the MessagesControlled didn't had a base version of the action method, but then i was getting "Controller method is not callable" errors, thats how i found out that symfony tried to call the parent method.

Why is this happening?

Update:

In the symfony LOG it shows the correct route if I make an error in the **parent** method
`INFO - Matched route "new_message_favorites" (parameters: "_controller": "BigBundle\Controller\VisitorMessagesController::sendToFavoritesAction", "_locale": "en", "_route": "new_message_favorites")`

But if I delete the method from the parent class, then it gives a `ReflectionException` that the method doesn't exists...

`Method BigBundle\Controller\MessagesController::sendToFavoritesAction() does not exist`

Update2:
There are 4 different methods mapped to routes in the `VisitorMessagesController` and all of them somehow map to the parent class.

Update3:
I've recreated the conditions `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver` which throws the exception:

```
$callable = [new VisitorMessagesController(), 'sendToFavoritesAction'];
if (!is_callable($callable)) { throw Ex }
```

The odd thing is, that in the `ControllerResolver` this resolves to **false** which results in the exception, but the same thing in an other Controller resolves to **true**

Comment: Is it possible that you have a similar route which might match, probably with some sort of placeholder?

Comment: I have a `/messages/new` also but no parameters, and it maps to a different method: `newMessageAction`

Comment: This is very strange. Have you already tried to clear caches?

Comment: yes, manually and with symfony console too :/

Comment: Check your `sendToFavorites` is declared `public`.

Comment: Comment out the other routes, clear cache and try again.  I know you said you don't have any other matching routes but you almost certainly do.  Or else you have two copies of your controller code and you are editing a different copy.

Comment: I double- and triple-checked if there are duplicates; I can't find any. I've commented out the whole route table as you suggested, and yielded the same result.

Comment: Check your spelling for VisitorMessagesController::sendToFavoritesAction

Comment: I've copy/pasted the definitions directly from the files into the description, you can check them too; but I've done it like 10 times. There is no type-o.

Comment: It's gotta be a simple typo somewhere.  Can you post your complete code to a github repository?

Comment: Unfortunately that is out of the question.

Comment: Sometimes when I get stuck I'll just make a brand new project and then copy stuff from the old one until I encounter the error.  I suppose you could check the appDevUrlMatcher in the cache.  Might offer a clue.

Comment: make sure you don't call parent::sendToFavorites($request) in VisitorMessagesController->sendToFavorites

Comment: In Symfony console, `run debug:router` (or `router:debug` for pre-2.7). That will give you a list of all your routes and their names

Comment: if `$callable = [new VisitorMessagesController(), 'sendToFavoritesAction']; is_callable($callable) === false;` then it has nothing to do with symfony or symfony routing. Check your classes and namespaces. I am sure there are two different classes with the same name

Comment: Make dump() of new VisitorMessagesController() to check what is actually created

Comment: Do you use JMSDiExtraBundle? Could be this bug: https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSDiExtraBundle/issues/186

Comment: @simon.ro you should make it an answer, and ill accept it; that was it!

Comment: @zedling glad to hear that! I made it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue in jms/di-extra-bundle that causes this bug: See https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSDiExtraBundle/issues/186

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs if you don't declare your method `sendToFavorites` as public. So it is not callable by the kernel. Please check this point.

Comment: It is for sure public; ill update the description to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete symfony cache /dev directory to be sure that this is no cache issue.
2. Search through whole project for `sendToFavorites` if there is no extra declaration for this route.
3. I also would say this is a typo, but if you say you checked it so many times...